# Remove buttons from Data Tables Color Admin Templete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have bootstrap color admin template, and i have used ([Color Admin Table With Button](http://seantheme.com/color-admin-v2.0/admin/html/table_manage_buttons.html)) now I want to remove copy button from data-tables. is there any way i can remove? I have placed following code in my java script please check.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         TableManageButtons.init();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
$('#data-table').DataTable( {
    buttons: [
        'print','csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
   ]
});
```